# ABP Framework with Angular UI and Auth0 Authentication

Tags: angular, auth0, abp

I am very new to the ABP.
I am using ABP community version with Angular front end.

The start up project works fine as instructed. Now I am trying to implement the Auth0 Authentication instead of ABP Authentication.
I already spent a lot of time googling and trying to implement the solution mentioned at
https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/Authentication-Customization/src/Acme.BookStore.Web/BookStoreWebModule.cs

But unfortunately it does not work.

Could somebody please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication in Abp is built on [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),
In angular, you can use well-known supported package to help you with basic operations:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I am now able to login and get authenticated by auth0 using OIDC in angular.
Only thing is that when I log out , it does not logout completely.
After log out if I login again , it does not ask for any credentials and directly logs me in.

Comment: After it logs out it redirects again to the angular app (where it should clean cookies and local storage),  You can do it manually but you should not need to, abp handles it automatically, for more info, watch: https://youtu.be/nyUD-CeBSiE